# Shorewall SHOW DYNAMIC command doesn't work

Tags: linux, shorewall

Setting up shorewall dynamic zones, http://shorewall.net/Dynamic.html shows the command `shorewall show dynamic zone` where zone is one of your zones.  I can get the `add` and `delete` commands to work, but not the `show dynamic` command.

Here is a shell session, with output from `ipset list` that proves that the items are indeed there.

```
$ ipset list CPREM_br0
Name: CPREM_br0
Type: hash:ip
Header: family inet hashsize 1024 maxelem 65536 
Size in memory: 16520
References: 66
Members:
192.168.85.153

$ shorewall add br0:192.168.85.200 CPREM
Host br0:192.168.85.200 added to zone CPREM

$ shorewall show dynamic CPREM

$ ipset list CPREM_br0
Name: CPREM_br0
Type: hash:ip
Header: family inet hashsize 1024 maxelem 65536 
Size in memory: 16536
References: 66
Members:
192.168.85.153
192.168.85.200

$ shorewall delete br0:192.168.85.200 CPREM
Host br0:192.168.85.200 deleted from zone CPREM

$ ipset list CPREM_br0                     
Name: CPREM_br0
Type: hash:ip
Header: family inet hashsize 1024 maxelem 65536 
Size in memory: 16536
References: 66
Members:
192.168.85.153
```

I am using the packaged version from Ubuntu 12.04 (4.4.26.1-1)